# Community for internal users - licensing

Tags: community, customer-community

I have a requirement all the employee in company can access salesforce. But client is not ready to buy that much user license. So we had a suggestion that create a community cloud and give access to all the employee through community cloud.

I get to know that the community user license should only be used by external user and and if it is used by employee of the company then it is violation of community cloud license. Can anyone here put some light on it. Do do we have any alternative solution for this, please suggest.

Comment: Communities for internal users are available via Platform user license + perm set to enable community features. Not as cheap as pure external but not anywhere as expensive as full-blown internal such as Sales Cloud. See linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real alternative. They should purchase the additional licenses as soon as possible. If they are found out before then, this could result in salesforce.com charging them retroactively for the number of CRM licenses they would have had to buy to support these "community" users as CRM users. This is laid out in the various Service Agreements for Communities and the Master Service Agreement. Nobody, either salesforce.com nor your client, really wants to go through this process.